# Simple interpreter written in Haskell, saves up print output until the end, instead of when it comes across a print statement

Tags: haskell, io, interpreter, monads

Below is my attempt at a very simple interpreter which is translated from the Java version of the program described in Chapter 1 of "modern compiler implementation in Java" by Andrew w. Appel, and operates directly upon a tree which represents the language.

Basically, my problem is that it saves up all the output until the end before anything at all is printed. I'm really just looking for advice on how to restructure it so that the "print" statements are printed as they are interpreted.

```
module Interpreter where

--------------------------------------------------------------------

type Id         =   [Char]
type Output     =   [Char]
type Value      =   Int
type Table      =   [(Id, Value)]

data Stm        =   CompoundStm Stm Stm |
                    AssignStm Id Exp |
                    PrintStm ExpList deriving Show

data Exp        =   IdExp Id |
                    NumExp Value |
                    OpExp Exp Op Exp |
                    EseqExp Stm Exp deriving Show

data ExpList    =   PairExpList Exp ExpList |
                    LastExpList Exp deriving Show

data Op         =   Plus | Minus | Times | Div deriving Show

--------------------------------------------------------------------

example ::  Stm
example =   CompoundStm (AssignStm "a" (OpExp (NumExp 5) Plus (NumExp 3))) 
            (CompoundStm (AssignStm "b" (EseqExp (PrintStm (PairExpList (IdExp "a")
             (LastExpList (OpExp (IdExp "a") Minus (NumExp 1))))) (OpExp (NumExp 10) Times
              (IdExp "a")))) (PrintStm (LastExpList (IdExp "b"))))

--------------------------------------------------------------------

tableUpdate                             ::  Table -> Id -> Value -> Table
tableUpdate t i v                       =   (i,v):t

tableLookup                             ::  Table -> Id -> Value
tableLookup ((x,v):t) i | x == i        =   v
tableLookup ((x,v):t) i | x /= i        =   tableLookup t i

--------------------------------------------------------------------

execute                                 ::  Stm -> IO()
execute s                               =   putStr ((\(o,_)->o) (interpStm s ("",[])))

interpStm                               ::  Stm -> (Output, Table) -> (Output, Table)
interpStm (CompoundStm l r) ot          =   interpStm r (interpStm l ot)
interpStm (PrintStm el) (o,t)           =   (interpExpList el o t)
interpStm (AssignStm i e) (o,t)         =   f i (interpExp e (o,t))
        where
            f i (v,o,t)                 =   (o, tableUpdate t i v)

interpExp                               ::  Exp -> (Output, Table) -> (Value, Output, Table)
interpExp (IdExp i) (o,t)               =   (tableLookup t i, o, t)
interpExp (NumExp v) (o,t)              =   (v, o, t)
interpExp (EseqExp s e) ot              =   interpExp e (interpStm s ot)
interpExp (OpExp l op r) (o,t)          =   f (interpExp l (o,t)) op r
        where
            f (v,o,t) op r              =   g v op (interpExp r (o,t))
            g v1 Plus (v2,o,t)          =   (v1 + v2, o, t)
            g v1 Minus (v2,o,t)         =   (v1 - v2, o, t)
            g v1 Times (v2,o,t)         =   (v1 * v2, o, t)
            g v1 Div (v2,o,t)           =   (v1 `div` v2, o, t)

interpExpList                           ::  ExpList -> Output -> Table -> (Output, Table)
interpExpList (LastExpList e) o t       =   f (interpExp e (o,t))       
        where
            f (v, o, t)                 =   (o ++ (show v) ++ "\n", t)
interpExpList (PairExpList e el) o t    =   f (interpExp e (o,t))
        where
            f (v, o, t)                 =   interpExpList el (o ++ (show v) ++ " ") t
```

Comment: You would have to make use a combined monad of StateT (for the Table) and IO for interactive printing (note, IO cannot be a transformer) . If this sounds like gobble-de-gook, then I wouldn't worry about trying to interactively print output just yet and first consider the simpler problem of using a State monad for plumbing the updateable Table through your code.

Comment: I did an advanced functional programming module on my course so I have used the State monad before, but I still don't completely understand how it works, so I'd struggle to build a combined IO/ST monad, do you know where I could have a proper read-up on the state monad? I'll see about rewriting Table as a ST monad to begin with though

Comment: A state monad is a good idea for readability and reducing the likelihood of bugs, but it's certainly not necessary.  Simply converting your code to IO will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your use of an accumulator is making the output unnecessarily strict. Accumulators are good in strict languages because they allow tail recursion; in lazy languages, they are unnecessary (and often bad). I've rewritten your code below to not use one.

```
module Interpreter where

--------------------------------------------------------------------

type Id         =   [Char]
type Output     =   [Char]
type Value      =   Int
type Table      =   [(Id, Value)]

data Stm        =   CompoundStm Stm Stm |
                    AssignStm Id Exp |
                    PrintStm ExpList deriving Show

data Exp        =   IdExp Id |
                    NumExp Value |
                    OpExp Exp Op Exp |
                    EseqExp Stm Exp deriving Show

data ExpList    =   PairExpList Exp ExpList |
                    LastExpList Exp deriving Show

data Op         =   Plus | Minus | Times | Div deriving Show

example ::  Stm
example =   CompoundStm (AssignStm "a" (OpExp (NumExp 5) Plus (NumExp 3))) 
            (CompoundStm (AssignStm "b" (EseqExp (PrintStm (PairExpList (IdExp "a")
             (LastExpList (OpExp (IdExp "a") Minus (NumExp 1))))) (OpExp (NumExp 10) Times
              (IdExp "a")))) (PrintStm (LastExpList (IdExp "b"))))

--------------------------------------------------------------------

tableUpdate                             ::  Table -> Id -> Value -> Table
tableUpdate t i v                       =   (i,v):t

tableLookup                             ::  Table -> Id -> Value
tableLookup ((x,v):t) i | x == i        =   v
tableLookup ((x,v):t) i | x /= i        =   tableLookup t i

--------------------------------------------------------------------

execute                                 ::  Stm -> IO()
execute s                               =   putStr ((\(o,_)->o) (interpStm s []))

interpStm                               ::  Stm -> Table -> (Output, Table)
interpStm (CompoundStm l r) t           =   let (o, t') = interpStm l t in
                                            let (o', t'') = interpStm r t' in
                                            (o ++ o', t'')
interpStm (PrintStm el) t               =   interpExpList el t
interpStm (AssignStm i e) t             =   let (v, o, t') = interpExp e t in
                                            (o, tableUpdate t' i v)

interpExp                               ::  Exp -> Table -> (Value, Output, Table)
interpExp (IdExp i) t                   =   (tableLookup t i, "", t)
interpExp (NumExp v) t                  =   (v, "", t)
interpExp (EseqExp s e) t               =   let (o, t') = interpStm s t in
                                            let (v, o', t'') = interpExp e t' in
                                            (v, o ++ o', t'')
interpExp (OpExp l op r) t              =   let (v, o, t') = interpExp l t in
                                            let (v', o', t'') = interpExp r t' in
                                            (g v op v', o++o', t'')
        where
            g v1 Plus v2                =   v1 + v2
            g v1 Minus v2               =   v1 - v2
            g v1 Times v2               =   v1 * v2
            g v1 Div v2                 =   v1 `div` v2

interpExpList                           ::  ExpList -> Table -> (Output, Table)
interpExpList (LastExpList e) t         =   let (v, o, t') = interpExp e t in
                                            (o ++ show v ++ "\n", t')
interpExpList (PairExpList e el) t      =   let (v, o, t') = interpExp e t in
                                            let (o', t'') = interpExpList el t' in
                                            (o ++ show v ++ " " ++ o', t')
```

With this change, the output comes properly lazily.

You'll notice that there's a *lot* of repeated code of the form `let (value, newTable) = f oldTable in ...`, and a *lot* of repeated code of the form `let (output, value) = exp; (moreOutput, value) = exp2 in (output ++ moreOutput, exp3)`. There are a couple of monads that write this code for you! Here's an example using StateT Table (Writer Output):

```
module Interpreter where

import Control.Monad.Writer
import Control.Monad.State
import Data.Maybe

--------------------------------------------------------------------

type Id         =   [Char]
type Output     =   [Char]
type Value      =   Int
type Table      =   [(Id, Value)]

data Stm        =   CompoundStm Stm Stm |
                    AssignStm Id Exp |
                    PrintStm ExpList deriving Show

data Exp        =   IdExp Id |
                    NumExp Value |
                    OpExp Exp Op Exp |
                    EseqExp Stm Exp deriving Show

data ExpList    =   PairExpList Exp ExpList |
                    LastExpList Exp deriving Show

data Op         =   Plus | Minus | Times | Div deriving Show

type InterpreterM = StateT Table (Writer Output)

example ::  Stm
example =   CompoundStm (AssignStm "a" (OpExp (NumExp 5) Plus (NumExp 3))) 
            (CompoundStm (AssignStm "b" (EseqExp (PrintStm (PairExpList (IdExp "a")
             (LastExpList (OpExp (IdExp "a") Minus (NumExp 1))))) (OpExp (NumExp 10) Times
              (IdExp "a")))) (PrintStm (LastExpList (IdExp "b"))))

--------------------------------------------------------------------

tableUpdate                             ::  Id -> Value -> InterpreterM ()
tableUpdate i v                         =   modify ((i,v):)

tableLookup                             ::  Id -> InterpreterM Value
tableLookup i                           =   gets (fromJust . lookup i)

--------------------------------------------------------------------

execute                                 ::  Stm -> IO ()
execute s                               =   putStr . execWriter $ evalStateT (interpStm s) []

interpStm                               ::  Stm -> InterpreterM ()
interpStm (CompoundStm l r)             =   interpStm l >> interpStm r
interpStm (PrintStm el)                 =   interpExpList el
interpStm (AssignStm i e)               =   interpExp e >>= tableUpdate i

interpExp                               ::  Exp -> InterpreterM Value
interpExp (IdExp i)                     =   tableLookup i
interpExp (NumExp v)                    =   return v
interpExp (EseqExp s e)                 =   interpStm s >> interpExp e
interpExp (OpExp l op r)                =   liftM2 (g op) (interpExp l) (interpExp r)
        where
            g Plus  v1 v2               =   v1 + v2
            g Minus v1 v2               =   v1 - v2
            g Times v1 v2               =   v1 * v2
            g Div   v1 v2               =   v1 `div` v2

interpExpList                           ::  ExpList -> InterpreterM ()
interpExpList (LastExpList e)           =   interpExp e >>= \v -> tell (show v ++ "\n")
interpExpList (PairExpList e el)        =   interpExp e >>= \v -> tell (show v ++ " ") >> interpExpList el
```

There are plenty of other changes that could be suggested from here, but hopefully you agree that this final form is much, much nicer to read than the previous one.

Answer (score 2):

To print output on the fly, the interpreter functions `interpStm`, `interpExp`, and `interpExpList` should print output instead of saving it.  You will have to convert those functions to run in the `IO` monad, which involves many changes but the process is straightforward.  Since output isn't being saved, the new functions will not have an `Output` parameter or return value.

The actual call to print happens in `interpExpList`.  The statements `print v; return t` says that the value `v` will be printed before any subsequent statement reads the store `t`.  For a reasonable definition of the other functions, this will produce the execution order you want.  If you want to be more explicit about the requirement that 'v' is printed before a subsequent statement executes, you can convert the code to CPS.

```
interpExpList (LastExpList e) t = do
  (v, t) <- interpExp e t
  print v
  return t
-- Code for PairExpList is similar
```

As a side note, `ExpList` is isomorphic to `[Exp]` minus the empty list.  Consider using `[Exp]` instead of `ExpList`.

Comment: thanks for your response, the problem with making interpExpList have type IO() is that within an ExpList you can have an Exp -> (Stm, Exp) and the Stm may contain another print statement. This would involve a pure function calling an impure function and isn't possible by my current understanding. Also, I know a list implementation would be better, but I was just translating the java classes directly to begin with.

Comment: Isn't it possible to use a `Writer` monad instead of relying onto `IO`?

Comment: @FUZxxl Writer monads are pure, they can't access stdout or file handles. (Well, technically all monads are pure. What I mean is that it is possible to escape the writer monad safely in a pure computation)

Comment: @Tom Continuation Passing Style. See Control.Monad.Cont.

Comment: @nomadic And thatcis their advantage. You can either print the result out or save it.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been closed for a while, but I recently solved this problem and thought people might wish to see how I ended up solving it.

Doing it this way, the print statements are actually printed to the screen as soon as the list of expressions descended from it are finished being evaluated:

```
module IOInterpreter where

import Data.Char

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

type Id      =  [Char]
type Output  =  [Char]
type Value   =  Int
type Table   =  [(Id, Value)]

data Stm     =  CompoundStm Stm Stm |
                AssignStm Id Exp |
                PrintStm ExpList deriving Show

data Exp     =  IdExp Id |
                NumExp Value |
                OpExp Exp Op Exp |
                EseqExp Stm Exp deriving Show

type ExpList =  [Exp]

data Op      =  Plus | Minus | Times | Div deriving Show

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

example :: Stm
example = CompoundStm (AssignStm "a" (OpExp (NumExp 5) Plus (NumExp 3)))
            (CompoundStm (AssignStm "b" (EseqExp (PrintStm [IdExp "a",
             OpExp (IdExp "a") Minus (NumExp 1)]) (OpExp (NumExp 10) Times
              (IdExp "a")))) (PrintStm [IdExp "b"]))

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

tableUpdate :: Table -> Id -> Value -> Table
tableUpdate t i v = (i,v):t

tableLookup :: Table -> Id -> Value
tableLookup ((x,v):t) i | x == i = v
tableLookup ((x,v):t) i | x /= i = tableLookup t i

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

execute :: Stm -> IO()
execute s = do
    interpStm s []
    return ()

interpStm :: Stm -> Table -> IO Table
interpStm (CompoundStm s1 s2) t = do
    t' <- interpStm s1 t
    interpStm s2 t'
interpStm (AssignStm i e) t = do
    (v, t') <- interpExp e t
    return $ tableUpdate t' i v
interpStm (PrintStm es) t = do
    (s, t') <- interpExpList es t
    putStrLn s
    return t'

interpExp :: Exp -> Table -> IO (Value, Table)
interpExp (NumExp v) t = return (v, t)
interpExp (IdExp i) t = return (tableLookup t i, t)
interpExp (EseqExp s e) t = do
    t' <- interpStm s t
    interpExp e t'
interpExp (OpExp e1 o e2) t = do
    (v1, t') <- interpExp e1 t
    (v2, t'') <- interpExp e2 t'
    return (f o v1 v2, t'')
    where
        f Plus v1 v2 = v1 + v2
        f Minus v1 v2 = v1 - v2
        f Times v1 v2 = v1 * v2
        f Div v1 v2 = v1 `div` v2

interpExpList :: ExpList -> Table -> IO (String, Table)
interpExpList [] t = return ("", t)
interpExpList (e:es) t = do
    (v, t') <- interpExp e t
    (s, t'') <- interpExpList es t'
    return $ (show v ++ " " ++ s, t'')
```